# Jenkins SSH slave fails to create /home/<user>/jenkins

Tags: linux, ssh, jenkins, amazon-ec2

When configuring an ssh slave on Jenkins, which runs on an ec2 instance, I get the following error message when I click on the "Launch Slave Agent".

```
[08/06/14 18:41:46] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22.
[08/06/14 18:41:46] [SSH] Authentication successful.
[08/06/14 18:41:46] [SSH] The remote users environment is:
[08/06/14 18:41:46] [SSH] Starting sftp client.
[08/06/14 18:41:46] [SSH] SFTP failed. Copying via SCP.
[08/06/14 18:41:46] [SSH] Remote file system root /home/<user>/jenkins does not exist. Will try to create it...
Failed to create /home/<user>/jenkins
[08/06/14 18:41:46] [SSH] Copying latest slave.jar...
hudson.util.IOException2: Could not copy slave.jar into '/home/<user>/jenkins' on slave
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.copySlaveJarUsingSCP(SSHLauncher.java:967)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.copySlaveJar(SSHLauncher.java:926)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.launch(SSHLauncher.java:596)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:228)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error during SCP transfer.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.SCPClient.put(SCPClient.java:523)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.copySlaveJarUsingSCP(SSHLauncher.java:965)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote scp terminated unexpectedly.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.SCPClient.readResponse(SCPClient.java:50)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.SCPClient.sendBytes(SCPClient.java:140)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.SCPClient.put(SCPClient.java:519)
    ... 8 more
[08/06/14 18:41:46] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Jenkins configuration for this node is as follows :

[image: Jenkins Config]

Please note that I've set JavaPath property because Jenkins "Couldn't figure out the Java version of java" (that's the error message I was getting)

Any idea how I could fix this issue ? Thanks

Comment: replace the text `<user>` with something that actually exists?

Comment: What does <user> stands for? What do you expect using it?

Comment: in my case <user> stands for ec2-user, but it could be any user running the jenkins ssh slave

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you get any solution @PapelPincel?

Comment: @rohit_kadam sorry, I don't have access to the jenkins server anymore. I wish I could help

Comment: the user path for ec2 instances is `ubuntu`,
you can confirm with `pwd` command after entering with your pem key.
so try changing `<user>` by `ubuntu`.

Answer (score 1):

I have had same issue. After reading the following post [talking about new version](https://java.net/projects/hudson/lists/users/archive/2011-12/message/59), realized something wrong on the SSH plugin that i'm using.

So I have visited to Manage plugins --> Installed --> searched 'SSH'  (disabled SSH related clients by removing selection) 
Basically you need:

- Disabled - SSH Slaves plugin (probably comes with Jenkins)
- Added SSH plugin (version 2.4).

Which resolved the issue, that i have had and successfully connected after other setups shown in this doc from step 6, [JENKINS-SETTING UP MASTER SLAVE ENVIRONMENT](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/basic/anonymous/api/library/a82c60c3-d3d9-4444-9f9f-63678cf12c17/document/436e8a19-1b13-459d-9559-fb6cf9c4dc1f/media). ( slave.jar -jnlpUrl....) 
Hope this will help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a valid path on the ec2 instance to which the user has an access.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same thing, no environment variables
The remote users environment is:
(empty)
.
.
.

I set the home directory that i was using for a new one for the jenkins user (example: /jenkinsFolder) and enabled the shell for jenkins in /etc/passwd (it was disabled)
then I was able to see environment variables when launching the slave.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in the above configuration:

1 . java path

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

2. Remote FS Root. create a directory and add the full path of it.

   ```
   $mkdir -p /home/jenkins/node-files
   ```

[image]